# Die Aussprache der Endung -ow

Tags: pronunciation, person-names, place-name

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Why is the -ow in place names pronounced the way it is?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6940)*

Warum wird in Orts- und Familiennamen wie Pankow, Treptow und Bülow der Buchstabe *w* üblicherweise nicht ausgesprochen?

Comment: Den Grund kann ich nicht sagen, aber ich traf schon Leute, die haben die mitgesprochen.

Comment: Das scheint ein sehr Berlin spezifisches oder lokales Phänomen zu sein so weit ich das als Nicht-Deutscher beurteilen kann. -> Bülow ist der Name folgender Gebietskörperschaften in Mecklenburg-Vorpommern:

Bülow (bei Crivitz), Gemeinde im Landkreis Ludwigslust-Parchim
ein Ortsteil der Gemeinde Gutow, Landkreis Rostock
ein Ortsteil der Gemeinde Schorssow, Landkreis Rostock
ein Ortsteil der Gemeinde Königsfeld (Mecklenburg), Landkreis Nordwestmecklenburg -> Vielleicht hilft das beim Einkreisen des Problems...

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namen_auf_-ow

Comment: Das eigenartige ist, daß, obwohl diese Namen slawischen Ursprungs zu sein scheinen, das _w_ nicht gesprochen wird. Denn in russischen Namen und anderen Wörten, wie z. B. Попов, Громов, часов, ... wird das _w_ immer gesprochen.

Comment: @MartinPeters: auch -> '***Warschau = Warsaw***'

Comment: @mramosch Krakau liefert einen besseren Vergleich, da es auf Polnisch auf /-uf/ bzw. ‹-ow› endet, während Warschau /-ava/ und Breslau /-af/ ausgesprochen werden. Wären die Beispielnamen aus der Frage stärker germanisiert worden, könnten sie heute also auch _*Pankau, *Treptau_ und _*Bülau_ o.ä. lauten. /-o/ und /-au/ sind im deutschen Phoneminventar schon recht nahe beieinander.

Comment: @Crissov Ich habe Leute gekannt, die das -ow im eigenen Namen als -au gesprochen haben.

Comment: @Crissov in Dresden gibt es einen Ortsteil _Bülau_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sehr passend zu diesem Thema gibt es den Wikipedia-Artikel [Namen auf -ow](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namen_auf_-ow). Vereinfacht gesagt, sieht die Lage ungefähr so aus:

- Im Mittelalter hatten viele Orte am Wasser Namen germanischen Ursprungs, die auf *-ow* oder *-owe* endeten. Diese Endung ist mit den Wörtern *Au* und letztlich auch *aqua* verwandt und wurde im Rahmen des Lautwandels meist zu *-au*.
- Viele Orte vor allem im Nordosten des deutschen Sprachraums haben noch slawische Namen aus der Zeit der frühesten (bekannten) Besiedlung. Wenn diese auf *-ow* enden, dann ist das in der Regel ein slawischer Genitiv Plural. Beispiele: Grabow = [Ort der] Buchen, Buckow = [Ort der] Rotbuchen, Burow = [Ort der] Bauern. Das *w* in dieser Genitiv-Endung wird wohl in den meisten slawischen Sprachen heute noch mitgesprochen. Laut Takkat in einer Antwort zu derselben Frage auf Englisch ist das aber im vor allem relevanten Sorbischen heute nicht mehr der Fall. (Ich hab versucht, eine Bestätigung dafür zu finden, aber die Online-Quellenlage zum Sorbischen ist nicht so toll.) Jedenfalls wird es in Ortsnamen heute im Deutschen in der Regel nicht gesprochen.
- Familiennamen auf *-ow* sind meistens ebenfalls slawischen Ursprungs und bedeuten *Sohn des ...*. Mir ist nicht ganz klar, warum diese Endung wie ein Genitiv Plural aussieht. (Evt. bezieht sich das auf beide Eltern, identifiziert durch den Vater?) Hier wird das *w* in der Regel mitgesprochen, weshalb auch vor allem in neuerer Zeit häufig Schreibweisen mit *-ov/-off* verwendet werden. (Bei Transkriptionen kyrillischer Namen hat man ja die Wahl.)
- Es gibt Übergänge zwischen diesen drei Formen. In Gegenden mit vielen Namen auf *-ow* liegt eine Umdeutung auf *-au* nah und umgekehrt. Außerdem werden immer wieder mal Orte nach Personen benannt und umgekehrt.

Ganz klar scheint mir, dass es wegen der großen Zahl von Orten und Familien einen großen Regularisierungsdruck gibt und dass hier der Standard lautet: "Die Endung *-ow* wird in Ortsnamen wie *-oh* und in Familiennamen wie *-off* ausgesprochen."

Daneben gibt es aus phonetischen und historischen Gründen Durchlässigkeit zwischen den Schreibungen und Aussprachen der Ortsnamensendungen *-au* und *-ow* (mit stummem *w*) in beide Richtungen. Und andererseits werden von Familiennamen abgeleitete Ortsnamen und von Ortsnamen abgeleitete Familiennamen natürlich zunächst in für ihre Klasse untypischer Weise ausgesprochen, was auch hier eine Durchlässigkeit bewirkt.

Irgendwann im Mittelalter dürften die drei Klassen von Namen im Wesentlichen alle gleich ausgesprochen worden sein. Lautverschiebungen, die es in den meisten slawischen Sprachen nicht gab, haben dann in weiten Teilen Deutschlands aus *-ow* das heutige *-au* gemacht, im Norden und Osten aber eher *-ow* (gesprochen *-oh*). (Grund für die unterschiedliche Entwicklung war vermutlich, dass *-ow* in manchen Regionen mit einem richtigen *w* und in anderen mit einem *u* ausgesprochen wurde. Falls das stimmt, wurde *-ou* zu *-au* und *-ow* zu *-oh*.) Evt. wurde diese letztere Lautverschiebung sogar vom Sorbischen mitgemacht. Da sie (zumindest größtenteils) vor der größeren Verbreitung von Familiennamen stattfand, sind aber die meisten Familiennamen auf *-ow* spätere slawische Importe und deshalb nicht davon betroffen. (Sorbische Familiennamen auf *-ow* scheinen kaum ins Gewicht zu fallen. Ich hab auch den Eindruck, dass diese meist transparent von Ortsnamen abgeleitet sind und zumindest deshalb vermutlich mit stummem *w* ausgesprochen werden.)

Der Zustand dürfte stabil sein, weil die Ortsnamen auf *-ow* wohl etwa gleich großen Einflüssen in entgegengesetzte Richtungen ausgeliefert sind: Einerseits in Richtung Aussprache *-au* und andererseits in Richtung Aussprache *-off*. Die übliche Aussprache *-oh* kann man wohl als einen Kompromiss dazwischen ansehen.

Answer (score 0):

Die Endung -ow wird im Deutschen lang gesprochen mit geschlossenem o (z.B. Treptow), im Slawischen dagegen kurz mit offenem o (z.B. Pawlow). Aus dem Grund reduziert sich das w phonetisch einfach weg zum stummen w, da die Betonung auf dem langen o liegt. Im Slawischen klingt das w dann schon fast wie ein f.

Comment: Na ja, in _Bahnhof_ ist der Konsonant ja auch nicht geschwunden. Die pauschale Aussage über "das Slawische" überzeugt mich auch nicht richtig; im Russischen unterliegt ein *-v* der Auslautverhärtung, im Polnischen eher nicht. Interessant wäre, ob die Aussage aus der Parallelfrage zutrifft, wonach das *-v* im Sorbischen stumm sei.

Comment: Es endet auch nicht auf f wie bei Bahnhof, sondern auf w, was zum Weglassen führt.

Answer (score -4):

Weil diese Begriffe nicht aus dem Deutschen, sondern aus anderen Sprachen kommen und somit nicht den deutschen Ausspracheregeln folgen muessen.

Comment: Gibt es einen tatsächlichen Grund, warum du auf _ue_ bestehst? Das "because it's a valid way to write in German language" ist kein besonders gutes Argument; abgesehen davon, daß _ü_ zumindest auch ein "valid way" ist, sehen die Schreibregeln _ue_ usw. nur für den Fall vor, daß keine Umlautbuchstaben zur Verfügung stehen. Und das ist hier ja nicht der Fall.

Comment: @chirlu So schreibe ich immer. Viele Menschen habe keine deutsche Tastatur und somit Probleme äöü einzugeben. Ich mag diese "Extrawuerste" im Alphabet nicht. Meiner Meinung nach erschweren sie nur das Schreiben (auf vielen Tastaturen). Man koennte ja genauso gut fragen _Warum bestehst du auf ü?_ Also da ist fuer mich auch keine Begruendung sichtbar : ) Da es meine Antwort ist, moechte ich sie auch in meinem Stil halten. Ich bin uebrigens auch fuer _ß --> sz_. Dann haette man alle besonderen Zeichen eliminiert und niemand braeuchte sich mehr um diese Zeichen sorgen.

Comment: Nun, _ü_ entspricht den [Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) (und _ue_ nicht; einzig für _ss_ statt _ß_ gibt es in § 25 E2 eine eingeschränkte „Erlaubnis“) und außerdem dem üblichen Gebrauch in Zeitungen, Büchern usw. Es steht dir natürlich frei, anders zu schreiben; allerdings steht es anderen frei, deine Antworten wegen schlechter Lesbarkeit weniger gut zu bewerten. – Nach deinem Maßstab hast du in https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/26005/1 übrigens einen Fehler gemacht (_weiß_).

Comment: Das ß mit doppel s auszutauschen ist leider Schwachsinn, da man Vokale vor doppeltem Konsonant kurz ausspricht und somit die Aussprache aendert. ue ae und oe sind hingegen mit der gleichen Aussprache definiert wie äöü. Bitte vorher recherchieren, bevor du einfach behauptest, dass ae ou und ue nicht der Rechtschreibung entspraechen. Ob nun meine Antwort gut oder schlecht bewertet wird – es ist im Moment die einzige Antwort, die direkt auf die Frage antwortet, wenn das andere nicht sehen kuemmert mich das nicht, es wird schon auch Leute geben, denen die Antwort weiterhilft.

Comment: Die Schweizer leben recht gut ohne _ß_, selbst dann, wenn sie den Lenkern von Bussen Bussen erteilen. Mehrdeutigkeit hast du bei äöü ebenso (_individüll_, _Michäl_). – Zur Frage der Richtigkeit: Ich habe oben schon auf die Rechtschreibregeln verlinkt. In § 1 ist die grundsätzliche Zuordnung von Vokallauten zu ihrer Schreibung festgelegt; dort steht für die entsprechenden Laute „ü“, nicht „ü oder ue“. Wenn du also etwa _Kueste_ schreibst, bewegst du dich nicht auf dem Boden der amtlichen Regeln.

Comment: Das e wird in manchen Ortsnamen auch als Dehnungs-e verwendet , z.B. Oer Erkenschwick, Soest. Es als Umlaute zu verwenden ist untypisch. Und warum alles gleich machen? Auch in anderen Sprachen gibt es Sonderzeichen:Die Akzente im Französichen, der Kringel über dem a im Dänischen, so ein schnörkel unter dem c in ich weiß nicht welcher Sprache.......

Comment: "e" gibt es auch als Dehnungs-e: Soest, Oer, Oldesloe. Sonderzeichen sind auch in anderen Sprachen gebräuchlich: Akzente im Französichen, dieser Kringel über dem a im Dänischen, ein Schnörkel unter dem c in ich-weiß-nicht-welcher Sprache..... Diese Besonderheiten sollten erhalten werden und nicht wegen Tastaturtauglichkeit abgeschafft werden.